# Android - Slide Left To Right Animation Starting from Top of Layout to Bottom

Tags: android

On some pages in my app I have a long list of buttons on the page, and what I want to happen when the user opens that page is the layout slide in from left to to right, but the top of the layout starts first and ends with the bottom button sliding into place. I know how to to the slide in animation in XML, but not sure how I could get the other part done. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will get idea about this animation from following link
     https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator

check it out

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I cannot use a gradle dependency with Eclipse (as far as I know). Is there any other library you know of, or a way to use this without gradle?

Comment: if you cannot use gradle dependency, use code directly in eclipse, search for how to run gradle project in eclipse